# difference between UNHEX and X (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, guid, hex

What really is the difference between MySQL UNHEX and X when dealing with hexadecimal values in a database?

Eg.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE guidCol IN (UNHEX('hexadecimalstring'));

SELECT * FROM test WHERE guidCol IN (X'hexadecimalstring');
```

Both gives me exact result set. So is there any difference? Performance implications?

**Edit:** the underlying type of guidCol is binary of course

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`UNHEX()` is [a function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex), therefore you can do something like

```sql
SET @var = '41';
SELECT UNHEX(@var);
SELECT UNHEX(hex_column) FROM my_table;
```

`X`, on the other hand, is the syntax for a [hexadecimal litteral](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/hexadecimal-literals.html). You cannot do this:

```sql
SET @var = '41';
SELECT X@var; -- error (string litteral expected)
SELECT X'@var'; -- error (`@` is not a hexadecimal digit)
SELECT X(@var); -- returns NULL, not too sure about the reason... [edit: but this is probably why you are inserting NULL values]
SELECT X(hex_column) FROM my_table; -- returns NULL as well
```

This explains why you always get better performance with `X`: you are using a language construct instead of a function call. `X` does not need to evaluate a variable, since it expects a litteral string.

Answer (score 1):

Note that even in MySQL 5.6, the X'' notation has a length limit in the reference mysql client and UNHEX() does not (appear to). I do not know what the limit is for X'', as it is not officially documented but I have encountered it when trying to INSERT a BLOB. With X'' literal, mysql client threw a syntax error with a sufficiently long hex sequence while UNHEX() of the same sequence did not. Obviously, length is not an issue when it comes to an actual GUID, but I figured this is useful for anyone else using this question to answer mysql insertion of binary data in the general case.