# how can store hexadecimal value inside mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

1) how can store **hexadecimal** value inside **`MySQL`** database?
   ==> `i` want to store `SQL` data to `MySQL`.
   ==> `in` `SQL` data store inside image datatype that i want to store in `MySQL`
       database.
       how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126210/insert-hex-values-into-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712934/storing-hexadecimal-values-as-binary-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNHEX() for inserting and HEX() for selecting that HEXADECIMAL

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (UNHEX('ABCD1F'))
```

or

```
SELECT HEX(column) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNHEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) function to convert a hexstring with hex pairs to binary and [HEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) to do the other way round.

I.e.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES (UNHEX('4D2AFF'))
```

and

```
SELECT HEX(col) FROM tbl
```